# How does a Non US citizen gain SEC Accredited Investor Status?

Tags: investing, start-up, form-w-4

I am interested in investing in Startups via Angellist or other similar programs. How do Companies and individuals not based in the United States become a qualified Accredited Investor by the SEC?

What information do I have to provide and to whom?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [SEC requirements](http://www.sec.gov/answers/accred.htm):

> The federal securities laws define the term accredited investor in
>   [Rule 501 of Regulation D](http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/goodbye.cgi?ecfr.gpoaccess.gov/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=441856d07884ed3f0111d84a92d9765f&rgn=div5&view=text&node=17:2.0.1.1.12&idno=17#17:2.0.1.1.12.0.42.175) as:
>
> - a bank, insurance company, registered investment company, business development company, or small business investment company;
> - an employee benefit plan, within the meaning of the Employee Retirement Income Security Act, if a bank, insurance company, or
>     registered investment adviser makes the investment decisions, or if
>     the plan has total assets in excess of $5 million;
> - a charitable organization, corporation, or partnership with assets exceeding $5 million;
> - a director, executive officer, or general partner of the company selling the securities;
> - a business in which all the equity owners are accredited investors;
> - a natural person who has individual net worth, or joint net worth with the person’s spouse, that exceeds $1 million at the time of the
>     purchase, excluding the value of the primary residence of such person;
> - a natural person with income exceeding $200,000 in each of the two most recent years or joint income with a spouse exceeding $300,000 for
>     those years and a reasonable expectation of the same income level in
>     the current year; or
> - a trust with assets in excess of $5 million, not formed to acquire the securities offered, whose purchases a sophisticated person makes.

No citizenship/residency requirements.

Comment: Do non US residents need to go through the accreditation process or can they be unaccredited and invest in startups? Thanks

Comment: @blue14 I'll repeeat - there's no residency/citizenship requirement.

Comment: The same way like for all other things- call your broker, fill out form. Mine asks me all sorts of details regularly to update their paperwork ;)